# Forward requests and headers to different host using tomcat

Tags: tomcat, redirect, header, http-headers, request

I have a stand-alone tomcat server (no apache/nginx in front) that I need to configure to reroute  all incoming requests **and their headers** for a specific application to a different host. In other words, I need the URL

`https://host.company.com/app/<anything here after>`

redirected to

`https://newhost.company.com/app/<anything here after>`

such that

`https://host.company.com/app/v1/explore?id=foo&pw=bar&more=crap`

is redirected to

`https://newhost.company.com/app/v1/explore?id=foo&pw=bar&more=crap`

while not interfering with `https://host.company.com/app2` or `https://host.company.com/app3`.

Currently, I have [urlrewrite](https://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) installed in `webapps/app` like so:

1. webapps/app/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN"
           "https://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
   <urlrewrite>
       <rule>
           <name>Requests to /app/ will be redirected to https://newhost.company.com/app/</name>
           <from>^/(.*)$</from>
           <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">https://newhost.company.com/app/$1</to>
       </rule>
   </urlrewrite>
   ```
2. webapps/app/WEB-INF/web.xml:

   ```
   <filter>
       <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
       <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
       <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```

The redirect to `https://newhost.company.com` is working, however the headers are not forwarded, and that is a key element in making this work. So while this works fine:

`curl --compressed -H 'Accept-Encoding:gzip' --get 'https://newhost.company.com/app/v1/explore' --data-urlencode 'id=foo' --data-urlencode 'pw=bar' --data-urlencode 'more=crap'`

this does not

`curl --compressed -H 'Accept-Encoding:gzip' --get 'https://host.company.com/app/v1/explore' --data-urlencode 'id=foo' --data-urlencode 'pw=bar' --data-urlencode 'more=crap'`

And running the above with `-vv` reveals the issue (stripped down for clarity):

```
* Connected to host.company.com (w.x.y.z) port 443 (#0)
> GET /app/v1/explore?id=foo&pw=bar&more=crap HTTP/1.1
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: https://newhost.company.com/app/v1/explore
* Connected to newhost.company.com (w.x.y.z) port 443 (#1)
> GET /app/v1/explore HTTP/1.1
```

As you can see, the GET to newhost.company.com doesn't include any uri data starting with the '?'. When using a standard browser, the resulting URL is `https://newhost.company.com/app/v1/explore` which makes sense given the above. However, I need that uri data to get passed onto newhost.company.com, and I don't know how to get tomcat to do it.

Note: Putting apache/nginx/etc in front of tomcat is NOT an option for "security" purposes (not my requirement, edict from management)

Answer (score 0):

When using [urlrewrite](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) you need to add the use-query-string="true" into the urlrewrite.xml urlrewrite tag for it to pass through the query string parameters on the forwarded URL.

CHANGE FROM:

```
<urlrewrite>
```

CHANGE TO:

```
<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">
```